# iOS - Advertise as an iBeacon using Phonegap

Tags: cordova, plugins, ibeacon

Has anyone successfully used an iOS device to advertise as an iBeacon using cordova/phonegap?  I have done it with a native application (airLocate is a nice demo app to do just that).  What I am looking to do is advertise using a phonegap/cordova plugin.

I have the following plugin: https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon
   Using this plugin, I have monitored for beacons successfully, ranged for beacons successfully, but I am unable to advertise.  I have used the following code (from that site):

```
var uuid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
var identifier = 'advertisedBeacon';
var minor = 2000;
var major = 5;
var beaconRegion = new cordova.plugins.locationManager.BeaconRegion(identifier, uuid, major, minor);

// The Delegate is optional
var delegate = new cordova.plugins.locationManager.Delegate();

// Event when advertising starts (there may be a short delay after the request)
// The property 'region' provides details of the broadcasting Beacon
delegate.peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising = function(pluginResult) {
    console.log('peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising: '+ JSON.stringify(pluginResult.region));
};
// Event when bluetooth transmission state changes 
// If 'state' is not set to BluetoothManagerStatePoweredOn when advertising cannot start
delegate.peripheralManagerDidUpdateState = function(pluginResult) {
    console.log('peripheralManagerDidUpdateState: '+ pluginResult.state);
};

cordova.plugins.locationManager.setDelegate(delegate);

// Verify the platform supports transmitting as a beacon
cordova.plugins.locationManager.isAdvertisingAvailable()
    .then(function(isSupported){

        if (isSupported) {
            cordova.plugins.locationManager.startAdvertising(beaconRegion)
                .fail(console.error)
                .done();
        } else {
            console.log("Advertising not supported");
        }
    })
    .fail(function(e) { console.error(e); })
    .done();
```

This code runs successfully, but it does not advertise.  I have used a beacon scanner, but it does not pick it up.  I run the code to check if it's advertising, but it always comes back false:

```
cordova.plugins.locationManager.isAdvertising()
.then(function(isAdvertising){
    console.log("isAdvertising: " + isAdvertising);
})
.fail(function(e) { console.error(e); })
.done();
```

I also have asked for permission from the user via the following method:

```
cordova.plugins.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();
```

So, has anyone done this successfully?  I am out of ideas and hoping that someone out there has done it and can at least let me know that it's possible (relatively easily). :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally got the answer from someone on ibeacon plugin issues section.  You can see the answer here - kudos to cgewecke for the answer:

https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon/issues/231

But basically, you need to enable "Location Updates" in xcode (after you have built it with cordova).  Go to the project (where the general settings are), then go to Capabilities->Background Modes->click "Location updates".